# Make UIAlertView Button trigger function On Press

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

Currently I am using the following code to present a UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today's Entry Complete"
                        message:@"Press OK to submit your data!" 
                       delegate:nil 
              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
              otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

How do I get it so that when 'OK" is pressed, it triggers a function, say `-(void)submitData`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**NOTE:**

**Important:** UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIAlertViewDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert.

[Please check this out tutorial](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/)

["deprecated" means???](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6967533/675170)

> Objectvie C

.h file

```
    @interface urViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

.m file

```
// Create Alert and set the delegate to listen events
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today's Entry Complete"
                                                message:@"Press OK to submit your data!"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

// Set the tag to alert unique among the other alerts.
// So that you can find out later, which alert we are handling
alert.tag = 100;

[alert show];


//[alert release];


-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


    // Is this my Alert View?
    if (alertView.tag == 100) {
        //Yes


    // You need to compare 'buttonIndex' & 0 to other value(1,2,3) if u have more buttons.
    // Then u can check which button was pressed.
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {// 1st Other Button

            [self submitData];

        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1) {// 2nd Other Button


        }

    }
    else {
     //No
        // Other Alert View

    }

}
```

> Swift

The Swifty way is to use the new UIAlertController and closures:

```
    // Create the alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    // Create the actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("OK Pressed")
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
    }

    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present the controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using multiple UIAlertView instances that are not declared in the class's interface you can also set a tag to identify instances in your delegate method, for example:

somewhere on top of your class file myClass.m

```
#define myAlertViewsTag 0
```

creating the UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
    message:@"please press ok or cancel"
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.tag = myAlertViewsTag;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

the delegate method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == myAlertViewsTag) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            // Do something when cancel pressed
        } else {
            // Do something for ok
        }
    } else {
        // Do something with responses from other alertViews
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate when allocating the alertview, then use one of the UIAlertViewDelegate methods to call your own method, for example:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today's Entry Complete"
                                                message:@"Press OK to submit your data!"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self submitData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the `delegate` for your `UIAlertView`, before showing it. Then do the work in the delegate callback as such:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    if ([[alert buttonTitleAtIndex] isEqualToString:@"Do it"]) {
        // Code to execute on Do it button selection.
    }
}
```

My CWUIKit project over at https://github.com/Jayway/CWUIKit has an addition to `UIAlertView` that allow you to do the same thing but with blocks. Redusing the same operation for both creating, showing and handling the alert to this:

```
[[UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"My Title"
                         message:@"The Message"
               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
  otherTitlesAndAuxiliaryActions:@"Do it", 
                                 ^(CWAuxiliaryAction*a) {
                                    // Code to execute on Do it button selection.
                                 }, nil] show];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use blocks you can also use [MKAdditions](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/UIKitCategoryAdditions/tree/master/MKAdditions%20%22MKAdditions) to achieve this easily even for multiple UIAlertViews.

Just use a code similar to this sample:

```
[[UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"Test" 
                        message:@"Hello World" 
              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
              otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", nil]
                      onDismiss:^(int buttonIndex)
 {
     NSLog(@"%d", buttonIndex);
 }
 onCancel:^()
 {
     NSLog(@"Cancelled");         
 }
 ] show];
```

You can find more information in this tutorial: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-block-based-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet

Answer (score 0):

Little more clarification,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
       //handles title you've added for cancelButtonTitle
        if(buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
            //do stuff
        }else{
           //handles titles you've added for otherButtonTitles
            if(buttonIndex == 1) {
                // do something else
            }
            else if(buttonIndex == 2) {
                // do different thing
            }
        }
    }
```

Example,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Need your action!" 
message:@"Choose an option to continue!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not Need!" 
otherButtonTitles:@"Do Something", @"Do Different", nil];
[alert show];
```

[image]

(it's iOS7 screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

From iOS8 Apple provide new `UIAlertController` class which you can use instead of UIAlertView which is now deprecated, its is also stated in depreciation message

> UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle
>   of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead

So you should use something like this

> Objective C

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                 message:@"Message"
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                    //Handle your yes please button action here
                                }];

   UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                       //Handle no, thanks button                
                                    }];

   [alert addAction:yesButton];
   [alert addAction:noButton];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> Swift

The Swifty way is to use the new UIAlertController and closures:

```
    // Create the alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    // Create the actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("OK Pressed")
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
    }

    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present the controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```