# initWithFrame : reuseIdentifier : is deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode4, deprecated, reuseidentifier

In my project i've got a Deprecations warning, initWithFrame : reuseIdentifier : is deprecated

I don't know what it mean, could some one tell me how to resolve this warning
thanks

here is the short code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [itemsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

and the warning is on that line :

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell without using deprecated method initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815121/uitableviewcell-without-using-deprecated-method-initwithframereuseidentifier)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[Take a look at this Apple's page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell)

> Here Red-Highlighted Functions and Properties will be Removed in Future by Apple in upcoming SDK.

**so that we should avoid them while creating App.**

**Because we need longterm project which should run without crash.**

a deprecated method means it has been replaced/retired but is still valid in current version of the language. it should be avoided and can cause problems/errors. check the documentation which should list an alternative method you can use.

Here you should use the method

```
 - initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

Then your if loop would look like this

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This problem appears in Beginning IOS 5 Development by Mark, Nutting and La Marche. Some readers may come here from that book where the deprecated code appears on page 265. They may assume the fault is theirs!

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier: sectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
```

needs to be replaced by (as the contributors above point out)

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: sectionsTableIdentifier];
```

Notice that I have dropped the autorelease as well because Auto Reference Counting does not like it!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                   reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```