# What call should I be using instead of this deprecated method?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, deprecated

I have a *UITableViewController* which creates dynamically re-sizeable cells. The cell changes the size of the cell depending on the text content and the font size. (A tip found here.)

It uses a call to the following method which is deprecated:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

I have not been able to figure out which method to use instead and keeping my functionality. There is no reference in the Apple documentation.

How could I solve this?

Comment: See also [initWithFrame : reuseIdentifier : is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967506/initwithframe-reuseidentifier-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Standard"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Standard"] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/initWithFrame%3areuseIdentifier%3a) specifically states:

> *Deprecated in iOS 3.0.* Use `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` instead.

Comment: I searched  _initWithFrame_ and I found the wrong _initWithFrame_, where I found no reference to this information. My bad :(

Answer (score 1):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```